# Power Series Theorem being generlized for holomorphic functions on closed disks?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

The Power Series Theorem, as formally discussed in $\text{Proposition 1}$, be generalized to holomorphic functions on closed disks ?

$$\text{Proposition 1}$$

$\text{Power Series Theorem}$

Let $f$ be a holomorphic on an open set $\Psi$, assume that $D(P,r) \subset \Psi$. Then $f$ can be expanded to a power series on $D(P,r)$:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-P)^{n}, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, $$

where,

$$a_n= \frac{f^{(n)}(P)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(P,r)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } \, d \zeta$$

In summary:
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(P,r)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } \, d \zeta(z-P)^{n}, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,$$

Comment: If $\Psi$ is open and $\overline{D(P,r)} \subset \Psi$, there is some $r'>r$ such that $D(0,r') \subset \Psi$. So, the answer is yes...

Comment: ahhh okay thank you, can you give any hints on how one would proof it, also can you clearify what $r'$ ?

Comment: Show that for any compact $K \subset U$, with $U$ open, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $K+B(0,\epsilon) \subset U$.